# Can you reverse the order of a branca colormap?

Tags: python, colormap

I have a branca colormap, is it possible flip it's order?

e.g.
This:
[image]

To this:
[image]

Code:

```
import branca.colormap as cm
den_colormap = cm.linear.RdBu_11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import branca.colormap as cm

den_colormap = cm.linear.RdBu_11.colors
print('Original : \n', den_colormap)

den_colormap.reverse()
print('reversed : \n', den_colormap)

out = cm.LinearColormap(colors=den_colormap)
print('out : \n', out.colors)
```

Output:

```
Original : 
 [(0.403921568627451, 0.0, 0.12156862745098039, 1.0), (0.6980392156862745, 0.09411764705882353, 0.16862745098039217, 1.0), (0.8392156862745098, 0.3764705882352941, 0.30196078431372547, 1.0), (0.9568627450980393, 0.6470588235294118, 0.5098039215686274, 1.0), (0.9921568627450981, 0.8588235294117647, 0.7803921568627451, 1.0), (0.9686274509803922, 0.9686274509803922, 0.9686274509803922, 1.0), (0.8196078431372549, 0.8980392156862745, 0.9411764705882353, 1.0), (0.5725490196078431, 0.7725490196078432, 0.8705882352941177, 1.0), (0.2627450980392157, 0.5764705882352941, 0.7647058823529411, 1.0), (0.12941176470588237, 0.4, 0.6745098039215687, 1.0), (0.0196078431372549, 0.18823529411764706, 0.3803921568627451, 1.0)]

reversed : 
 [(0.0196078431372549, 0.18823529411764706, 0.3803921568627451, 1.0), (0.12941176470588237, 0.4, 0.6745098039215687, 1.0), (0.2627450980392157, 0.5764705882352941, 0.7647058823529411, 1.0), (0.5725490196078431, 0.7725490196078432, 0.8705882352941177, 1.0), (0.8196078431372549, 0.8980392156862745, 0.9411764705882353, 1.0), (0.9686274509803922, 0.9686274509803922, 0.9686274509803922, 1.0), (0.9921568627450981, 0.8588235294117647, 0.7803921568627451, 1.0), (0.9568627450980393, 0.6470588235294118, 0.5098039215686274, 1.0), (0.8392156862745098, 0.3764705882352941, 0.30196078431372547, 1.0), (0.6980392156862745, 0.09411764705882353, 0.16862745098039217, 1.0), (0.403921568627451, 0.0, 0.12156862745098039, 1.0)]

out : 
 [(0.0196078431372549, 0.18823529411764706, 0.3803921568627451, 1.0), (0.12941176470588237, 0.4, 0.6745098039215687, 1.0), (0.2627450980392157, 0.5764705882352941, 0.7647058823529411, 1.0), (0.5725490196078431, 0.7725490196078432, 0.8705882352941177, 1.0), (0.8196078431372549, 0.8980392156862745, 0.9411764705882353, 1.0), (0.9686274509803922, 0.9686274509803922, 0.9686274509803922, 1.0), (0.9921568627450981, 0.8588235294117647, 0.7803921568627451, 1.0), (0.9568627450980393, 0.6470588235294118, 0.5098039215686274, 1.0), (0.8392156862745098, 0.3764705882352941, 0.30196078431372547, 1.0), (0.6980392156862745, 0.09411764705882353, 0.16862745098039217, 1.0), (0.403921568627451, 0.0, 0.12156862745098039, 1.0)]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Even though the values are indeed reversed, the color palette looks exactly the same when calling `out` on a Jupyter Notebook. Found the error, it should be `out = cm.LinearColormap(colors=list(den_colormap))` now it works!

Answer (score 1):

- `cm.linear` is a collection of `LinearColormap` instances.
- `LinearColormap` has as attributes a list of colors `colors`, as well as a minimum value `vmin` and a maximum value `vmax`, that are used to map a value linearly to the colors.
- The `LinearColormap` initializer takes as arguments a list of colors, as well as the minimum and maximum values.

[Source](https://python-visualization.github.io/branca/_modules/branca/colormap.html)

---

So you can create a new `LinearColormap` instance based on an existing one, by passing the reversed the list of colors and using the same minimum and maximum values.

```
def reversed_colormap(existing):
    return cm.LinearColormap(
        colors=list(reversed(existing.colors)),
        vmin=existing.vmin, vmax=existing.vmax
    )
```

Example:

```
RdBu_11_reverse = reversed_colormap(cm.linear.RdBu_11)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Option 1 fails since a reversed list has no length and Option 2 produces a map which is just red.

Comment: OK, thanks. Then you need to convert the iterator returned by `reversed` to a list explicitly. Why Option 2 does not work, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

### Reversing the branca.colormap in 2023

Going from `cm.linear.RdBu_11`

[image: cm.linear.RdBu_11]

to reversed `cm.linear.RdBu_11`

[image: reversed cm.linear.RdBu_11]

There is no built-in function in branca, but a 2-liner gets the job done.

Note that you are modifying the **original colormap** which is probably not ideal. Calling the reverse function toggles the order back and forth.

```py
import branca.colormap as cm

original_colormap = cm.linear.RdBu_11
original_colormap.colors.reverse()

original_colormap
```